# how to set revision log message programatically in drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to set the revision log in a custom module in drupal 8, using $media->set("revision_log","test message")

and it doesnt work.  This method is working for all of the other fields. why doesnt it work for the revision_log?

Comment: What type of entity is `$media`?

Comment: It's a media entity

Comment: Try `$media->setRevisionLogMessage('foo');`. If you get an undefined method error, the entity type probably doesn't support revisions. If you don't get an error, you might have forgotten to save the entity

Comment: This question is too broad because it doesn't make clear what exactly doesn't work. At least, the question should show what error is given, if there is an error, and it should show more of the code used for the purpose.

Comment: From a single code line isn't possible to answer to _Why doesn't the code work?_ It could be that `$media` is not initialized, it is initialized with the wrong value, it contains a reference to an entity that doesn't support revisions or that doesn't have any *revision_log* property/field; the function/method containing that line is not called; the line is contained in a `if` statement that is not executed for many reason; the module containing that line is not installed; the shown line is not executed because it's commented out; there is another module that reverts any change done; etc etc.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235525/how-to-create-revision-for-a-node-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$media->setRevisionLogMessage('foo');