# How can I programmatically create a revision for a node?

Tags: entities

I have a `node` object and I need to create revisions for that node programmatically. When I tried as follows it's not working. Instead it's creating new nodes. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

```php
$node = Node::create([
  'nid' => $nid, // My desired node ID for the revision.
  'type' => $bundle_type,
  'field1' => $value1,
  'field2' => $value2,
]);

$node->revision = TRUE;
$node->save();
$node->setPublished(true);
$nid = $node->id();
print 'Created revision for node' . $nid;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
// Make this change a new revision
  $node->setNewRevision(TRUE);
  $node->revision_log = 'Created revision for node' . $nid;
  $node->setRevisionCreationTime(REQUEST_TIME);
  $node->setRevisionUserId($user_id);
  $node->save();
```

Use Above Code to create a revision. :)

Comment: How to specify the **author** when creating the revision ?

Comment: Hi , when i create new revision for a node its set as the **main node** , instead of the revision . How can i solve this ? Is there an **`$node->is_current = FALSE;`** utility ??

Comment: @RubberDuckIsKing It's in the answer, that's this part: `$node->setRevisionUserId($user_id);`

Comment: @RubberDuckIsKing It sounds like you're trying to create a forward draft revision (i.e. an unpublished draft).  The exact details of that depends on whether you're using Workbench Moderation, Content Moderation, or something else.  If the former, then something like `$node->moderation_state->target_id = 'draft';`

Comment: I thought I could get away with just calling `$node->setNewRevision(TRUE)` but it didn't work.  You have to set everything above for it to work.  Also, I used `$node->setRevisionLogMessage('Updated');` rather than setting `$node->revision_log` directly.

Comment: how to make sure the revision is in the right language ? it does not work with multilingual site

Comment: @RubberDuckIsKing @Dalin is correct. In my case, I had to add: `$node->set('moderation_state', 'draft');`

Answer (score 2):

For language specific revisions you can use below code sample:

```php
$storage =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$revision = $storage->load($nid);
$revision = $revision->getTranslation($languageCode);
$revision->setRevisionCreationTime(\Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime());
$revision= $storage->createRevision($revision);
$revision->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled the content moderation module, you must set the moderation state like this:

```php
$node->moderation_state->value = 'draft';
```